# Using Yum Install

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, yum

I understand that there are repositories from where we can download packages and certain repositories provide only certain packages.

I want know how to look for repositories that can provide packages that I require and that are compatible to my version of linux, which currently is RHEL 6.3

I want to install

```
yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel \
  openssl-devel zlib-devel
```

How do I locate repositories offering these packages ?

Comment: Note that all the packages given are available from the distro creator themselves.

Comment: All of these are in the Red Hat base repositories. You need to _actually pay for Red Hat_ if you want to use it. Otherwise use CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use pkg.org to locate repositories:

- http://pkgs.org/search/?keyword=repository

Additionally I usually just google for the package name adding/subtracting bits from it's name depending on which distro I'm looking for.

#### CentOS/RHEL:

- look for packages named el5 or el6 for either of these distros at version 5 or 6.

#### Fedora:

- look for packages named f# where # is a number like 14 for Fedora 14 or 18 for Fedora 18.

This is a good list of the repositories available, most include packages for all the variants (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL).

- http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

#### repolist

You can see what repos you do have with this command:

```
$ yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * updates: ftp.linux.ncsu.edu
73 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
repo id                                            repo name                                                                                 status
base                                               CentOS-6 - Base                                                                           6,315+66
*epel                                              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                               9,182
extras                                             CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                              6+7
updates                                            CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                             916
repolist: 16,419
```

#### References

- [CentOS / RHEL: List All Configured Repositories](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-fedora-redhat-yum-repolist-command-tolist-package-repositories/)